# Unable to authorize WEB API requests from a site in different project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cors, owin

I have, what I think is a very common solution pattern, in Visual Studio:

1. ASP.NET MVC project that has a number angular-backed views ASP.NET
2. WEB API v2 project that serves that data to angularjs

I'm using OWIN with auth stored in application cookie approach
MVC and WEB API projects have this config:

```
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions             {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logout"),
        CookieDomain = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AuthCookieDomain"),
        CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
        CookiePath = "/",
        CookieHttpOnly = false,
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365),
        SlidingExpiration = true,           });

    // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider          app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

Web API asks for every call to be authenticated:

```
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
```

Cors is enabled in and Cors for OWIN is installed in Web API project.
Both projects are running under https:// localhost but with different ports at the moment
If I login into the MVC site thru browser and do a GET on a web api method, all is good.  However, if the site does the request, it gets an UNauthorized.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you found out what is wrong?

Comment: Nope, we did a workaround

Comment: if it works as a request from the api and not from the mvc then maybe you have mis-configured cors?

Comment: The cause of issue is most likely in CORS misconfiguration, however the author isn't sharing any details about how are the CORS configured nor he attempted to make fiddler OPTION request to debug it. Unless those details are provided, this question is off-topic.